# How do I combine .EXE commands in Perl?

Tags: perl, system, external-process

I have a set of .EXE commands. How do I get all those commands run in Perl as a single file?
Whats the process to call the .EXE files in Perl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Perl [`system()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) function will do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

system("prog1.exe");
system("prog2.exe");
```

Comment: don't forget to check exit codes from your system command, you might not want to run prog2 if prog1 failed

Answer (score 3):

TThe way to call system commands from perl is to use

```
system("String containing command + args here")
```

or if you want to perform some processing on the output, you use backticks

```
`command + args here`
```

You can use all your normal perl string manipulation oneliners with the backtick as well.